# NullPointerException occurs on calling getText() from EditText in onClickListener in DialogFragment

Tags: java, android

I have `DialogFragment` with custom layout that has an EditText. I am trying to get EditText value on 'ADD' Click but I have been getting `NullPointerException` and it crashes.

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

     final View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.add_note_dialog_fragment, null);
     alertDialogBuilder.setView(view);
     alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Add New Note: ");
     alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("ADD", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

             EditText noteTextEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.notesText);
             EditText noteTitleEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.noteTitle2);

             Editable noteText = noteTextEditText.getText();
             // ^^^ HERE I GET NULL POINTER EXCEPTION

             String y = noteText.toString();                 
             String noteTitle = noteTitleEditText.getText().toString();
             DatabaseHelper.addInABSTRACT_NOTES(noteText, noteTitle);
             Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ADDED ..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             dialog.dismiss();
         }
     });
```

Kindly suggest how can I get it working ? 
Thanks in advance.

---

LogCat:

```
07-08 00:08:47.030: E/AndroidRuntime(16500): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 00:08:47.030: E/AndroidRuntime(16500): Process: com.shumail.newsroom, PID: 16500
07-08 00:08:47.030: E/AndroidRuntime(16500): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-08 00:08:47.030: E/AndroidRuntime(16500):    at com.g_node.gca.abstracts.AddNoteDialogFragment$1.onClick(AddNoteDialogFragment.java:70)
07-08 00:08:47.030: E/AndroidRuntime(16500):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:166)
07-08 00:08:47.030: E/AndroidRuntime(16500):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-08 00:08:47.030: E/AndroidRuntime(16500):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-08 00:08:47.030: E/AndroidRuntime(16500):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
07-08 00:08:47.030: E/AndroidRuntime(16500):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 00:08:47.030: E/AndroidRuntime(16500):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-08 00:08:47.030: E/AndroidRuntime(16500):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-08 00:08:47.030: E/AndroidRuntime(16500):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-08 00:08:47.030: E/AndroidRuntime(16500):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

Layout XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"  >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/noteTitleLabel" android:text="Note Title: " 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/noteTitle2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"      
    android:inputType="text"
    android:hint="Enter Note Title..."
    android:gravity="top"
    android:layout_below="@+id/noteTitleLabel"
    android:singleLine="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/noteTextLabel" android:text="Note Content: " 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  android:layout_below="@+id/noteTitle2"  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/noteText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"      
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:hint="Enter Note Content..."
    android:lines="5"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:layout_below="@+id/noteTextLabel"
    android:singleLine="false" />
```

Comment: There are 2 possibilities: `noteTextEditText` is null or `noteTextEditText.getText()` returns null. Please verify which value is null. There is no need to call `toString()`

Comment: where do you set the contentView?  where do you actually show the alertDialog.. you create it but you never call .show()

Comment: I'm calling show() from the viewpager fragment. `addNoteFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "fragment_add_note");`

Comment: @Jens: Can you please tell how can I verify which value is null ? I have updated question with LogCat

Comment: @ShumailMohy-ud-Din if you remove the `toString()` method, and you get the exception is `noteTextEditText` null. Or use a debugger.

Comment: Ok I removed that and changed it to `Editable noteText = noteTextEditText.getText();` - Now it shows exception at this line. Means `noteTextEditText` is null ? Any way to correct it ?

Comment: Also Updated the Logcat & Code in Question. Please Help @Jens

Comment: My Bad @Jens. It was typo that caused error. Thankyou for helping. Removing tostring helped me figuring out the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the ID. I had written `R.id.notesText` by mistake whereas it was supposed to be `R.id.noteText`